# gl_FragColor.a makes my canvas transparent when using Multiply Blending mode

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've created a simple shader where the alpha `gl_FragColor.a` is 0 or 1, based on a sine wave:

```glsl
void main() {
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3( vUv.x, vUv.y, 0.0 );

    float sinWave = vUv.y + sin(time * 5.0 + vUv.x * 10.0) * 0.3 - 0.2;
    gl_FragColor.a = step(sinWave, 0.5);
}
```

The background is grey `(r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5)`. If I use `blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending` I get the following result, which behaves as I'd expect.

[image: Additive Blending mode]

However, if I use `blending: THREE.MultiplyBlending`, the parts where alpha = 0 make my whole canvas buffer transparent, showing all the way through the HTML background behind it:

[image: Multiply blending mode]

I presume this is because the framebuffer alpha undergoes the multiplication: `1.0 * 0.0 = 0.0`. I've read [Greggman's WebGL Fundamentals on alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html), where it suggests setting `alpha: false` to the WebGL context, but this is the result on the left, compared to what I'm trying to achieve on the right:

[image: Multiply blending, no alpha]
[image]

#### Question:

Is there any way to keep my canvas alpha set to 1.0 so it doesn't cut away at the background and behaves like the Additive mode? Is there a specific [gl.blendFunc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc) combination that I could use to achieve a similar result as seen with AdditiveBlending? I'm writing a smoke shader that will fade away over time, but I can't have the smoke make my canvas transparent as its alpha reaches 0.

[Click here to see live demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/j8nbLsxr/):

- Line 15: toggle WebGL alpha true/false
- Line 56: Toggle Multiply/Additive blending

I've also added the same via Code Snippet below:

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background:
        repeating-linear-gradient(to left, #f09 0px, transparent 10px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(#09f 0px, transparent 10px);
    background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f90;
    z-index: 1;
}
#webGLCanvas {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is all HTML Background 
This is all HTML Background 
This is all HTML Background
</h1>
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="webGLCanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.144.0/build/three.module.js";

let camera, mesh, renderer, material;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    const canvas = document.getElementById("webGLCanvas");
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2", {
        alpha: true,
      premultipliedAlpha: false 
    });
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        context: gl,
        canvas: canvas
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x888888, 1);
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height= window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.Camera();

    // Create material
    const VERT_SHADER = `
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    `;

    const FRAG_SHADER = `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        uniform float time;

        void main() {
            float sinWave = vUv.y + sin(time * 5.0 + vUv.x * 10.0) * 0.3 - 0.2;
            
            gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3( vUv.x, vUv.y, 0.0 );
            gl_FragColor.a = step(sinWave, 0.5);
        }
    `;

    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: {
            time: { value: 1.0 }
        },
        vertexShader: VERT_SHADER,
        fragmentShader: FRAG_SHADER,
        transparent: true,
        // Use this mode to see difference!            
        // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        blending: THREE.MultiplyBlending,
    } );
    
    // Create mesh
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
}

// Only take up 1/4th screen
function onWindowResize() {
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.domElement.style.transform = "scale(0.5)";
}

// Render material as full-screen quad
function animate() {
    material.uniforms[ 'time' ].value = performance.now() / 1000;
    renderer.render( mesh, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe https://jsfiddle.net/b57a9yhe/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @WestLangley! I could make the shader fade to white in the RGB channels to fake alpha for `Multiply`. But I’m wondering why `AdditiveBlending` shows the grey background when alpha is 0, [as in this screenshot](https://global.discourse-cdn.com/standard17/uploads/threejs/original/3X/7/5/75e5c5fb1c99b6af84f92cf11226524868e68bf8.jpeg) Shouldn’t the R and G channels add up to >1.0 on that top-right corner, independent of the alpha channel? It feels like Additive behaves different than Multiply; the alpha affects the colors in Additive, but it’s independent in Multiply.